# Question regarding the breakup of India from Eastern Gondwana

Tags: geophysics, climate, oceanography, plate-tectonics

I wanted to ask this question as it relates to a project I am working on. In this "timeline" when India broke away from Gondwana the Indian Plate took a small piece of land from Eastern Antarctica; forming a large island located south of India. Could the break up of the tectonic plates allowed for such a landmass to exist. If so, how would it affect the oceanography of the Indian ocean with its movement? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I must admit that I don't understand the question, in parts because the third to last sentence "Could the..." start like a question but doesn't end like one. Can you clarify?